# Stereo (3D) rendering on Android Smartphones with OpenGL? How?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Seeing as there are smartphones with 3D displayes coming out on the market I was wondering if it was possible to render in stereo using the Android 4.0 SDK. On a desktop I'd basically do the following:

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
//Draw image for left eye.
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
//Right eye.
```

So far I couldn't find out how to do this with the Android SDK. Is there any related call with a different naming or does this simply not exist in the official SDK yet? If it doesn't, is there any other Android/OpenGLES SDK out there that allows to do this?

Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a unified way of doing this. Each manufacturer has their own specific implementation. As far as I know it's all high level stuff, so probably not what you're looking for.

For HTC, it's in the OpenSense SDK:
http://htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk

For LG, there's a package in the Android SDK Manager called "Real3D by LGE". It's API level 10.